# Scale-Free graph, access the vertices of the graph

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I'm trying to generate a Scale-Free graph, according to the Barabasi-Albert Model. I used the `barabasi.game` function, gerating 1000 vertices of the graph:

```
library('igraph')
g <- barabasi.game(1000)
```

I would like, now, to pick at random a vertex of `g` and, among its neighbors, to pick at random another vertex. How can I access the vertices of the graph?

**Edit.** I had problems with the solution kindly suggested by G5W. For this graph:

[image]

I obtained, from the first instruction

```
RV<-sample(V(g), 1)
```

the result `RV=4`, but from the second

```
RVn<-sample(neighbors(g, RV, mode="all"), 1)
```

I obtained `RVn=1`. As we can see from the pic this is a mistake; moreover, instruction

```
neighbors(g, i)
```

returns

```
+ 1/10 vertex, named, from 57207c1: 
[1] 2
```

Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `V(g)`. This documentation was found [here](https://igraph.org/r/doc/V.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modified**

You can pick a random vertex and a random neighbor like this:

```
RV  = sample(V(g), 1)
NRV = neighbors(g, RV, mode="all")
RVn = ifelse(length(NRV) == 1, NRV, sample(NRV, 1))
```

This should work when RV has one neighbor or more.

I would like to mention that *most* vertices have only one neighbor, so the random selection of a neighbor doesn't do much.

```
table(sapply(V(g), function(v) length(neighbors(g, v, mode="all"))))
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  18  21  37  38  92 
657 183  67  35  12  11   3   7   4   6   2   4   1   2   2   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Thank you! In this way I could obtain RV = RVn. (I just executed the code) How can I avoid this?

Comment: A vertex should not be a neighbor of itself unless the graph contains loops. I thought that barabasi did not generate loops. Does your graph contain loops?

Comment: Ok, maybe I made a mistake. No, my graph does not contain loops

Comment: #G5W I found some problems. I edited the post, I'm sorry

Comment: Maybe `sample(unlist(list(neighbors(g, RV, mode="all"))), 1)`? Because otherwise I obatin `Error in as.igraph.vs(graph, v) : 
  Cannot use a vertex sequence from another graph.`

Comment: Sorry for the false starts. I think the updated answer should be OK.